# ICollection property is empty during OnValidSubmit()

Tags: entity-framework-core, datagrid, blazor, syncfusion

I am trying the free community version of Syncfusion Blazor SfGrid for my basic CRUD of a `ICollection` property. But while I am able to add, edit, delete at runtime (data is perfectly shown in the datagrid), my `ICollection` property is always empty during `OnValidSubmit()`...

1st: My data models look like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ContactPerson> ContactPersons { get; set; }
}

public class ContactPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

2nd: My create.razor uses my ContactForm.razor for reusability

```
<h1>Create</h1>
<hr />
<div style="margin: 50px">
    <ContactForm Contact="contact" OnValidSubmit="@CreateRecord" OnCancelButton="@CancelRecord"/>
</div>

@code {
    private Contact contact = new Contact
    {
        ContactPersons = new ContactPerson[0],
        ContactAddresses = new ContactAddress[0]
    };

    void CancelRecord()
    {
        uriHelper.NavigateTo("contact");
    }

    async Task CreateRecord()
    {          
        await http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Contact", contact);
        uriHelper.NavigateTo("contact");
    }
}
```

3rd: My ContactForm.razor looks like this (which I use for creating and editing a record):

```
@if (Contact == null)
{
    <text>Loading...</text>
}
else
{
    <EditForm Model="@Contact" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <SfTextBox @bind-Value="@Contact.AccountName" Placeholder="Account Name"></SfTextBox>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Contact.AccountName)"></ValidationMessage>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- List of Contact Persons -->
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                <SfGrid DataSource="@Contact.ContactPersons" Toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Cancel", "Update" })" AllowPaging="true">
                    <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true"></GridEditSettings>
                    <GridColumns>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ContactPerson.ID) IsPrimaryKey="true" HeaderText="ID"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ContactPerson.FirstName) HeaderText="First Name"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ContactPerson.MiddleName) HeaderText="Middle Name"></GridColumn>
                        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ContactPerson.LastName) HeaderText="Last Name"></GridColumn>                        
                    </GridColumns>
                </SfGrid>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Post and Back Link -->
        <hr />
        <div>
            <SfButton type="submit" CssClass="e-primary">Sumbit</SfButton>
            <SfButton type="button" CssClass="e-danger" @onclick="@OnCancelButton">Cancel</SfButton>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnCancelButton { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I encounter is that `Contact.ContactPersons` is empty when I pass it to my controller (webapi), and when I break at ``` CreateRecord() which is `` OnValidSubmit ```, and watch the variable `Contact.ContactPersons` in VS2019, the variable is empty and says

> Unable to Evaluate.

Please help me understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue not related to Blazor...

Since `ContactPersons` is of `ICollection<ContactPerson>` type, you should instantiate the ContactPersons field with a collection of ContactPerson objects like this:

```
 private Contact contact = new Contact
    {
        ContactPersons = new List<ContactPerson>()
       
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir Enet and sir Henk..I'm starting to understand this now..it is because ContactPersons is an Interface, it's really just holding a reference address? So I need to instantiate it with a List and because I don't know the exact number of entries it might receive, it's better to use a dynamic List over a fixed array of ContactPersons! Thank you very much again!!